# Is it possible to reuse a widget in Tkinter? If so, how can I do it using classes?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm using classes and such to make a calculator in Tkinter, however I want to be able to be able to reuse widgets for multiple windows. How can I do this if this is possible?

Comment: Why do you want to reuse widgets?

Comment: I'm making a calculator, as mentioned and I want to have a drop down menu on the window, that when selected it closes the root window and opens another, and I want to have the drop down menu on all the different pages, 5 or 6 in all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you commented:

> I'm making a calculator, as mentioned and I want to have a drop down menu on the window, that when selected it closes the root window and opens another, and I want to have the drop down menu on all the different pages, 5 or 6 in all

In this case, just write a function that creates the menu.
Then call that function when creating each of the windows.

Answer (score 1):

A widget may only exist in one window at a time, and cannot be moved between windows (the root window and instances of `Toplevel`).